# Direct Batch file to current-user Documents folder

Tags: batch-file, cd

I'm on Win 10 with my Documents folder moved to my E: drive via the Windows tool. I need to run a batch file to locate this path, change the current directory within the batch file and copy files from sub-folders to another drive. The batch file needs to be able to be run from any location upon the local PC.

The following returns E:\Users\username\Documents\Test\T1 but it does not actually change the directory within the batch file.

```
@echo
for /f "tokens=3*" %%p in ('REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v Personal') do set DocumentsFolder=%%p
echo %DocumentsFolder%\Test\T1\
```

All copy command lines are in the same section of the batch file. Will one cd at the start of this section effect the whole section?

I would very much appreciate any advice. I frequent this site when looking to learn new things but I could not find this answer.

Thanks Much

Comment: You couldn't just add *one cd at the start of the section* and figure out if it will work or not yourself?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and to answer, yes I did. It does not change the directory.

Comment: You should examine `%USERPROFILE%`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue is simply that you needed to change drives as well as the directory.

The easiest way to do that is to use the `/D` option with `CD`, enter `CD /?` at the command prompt for its usage.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "RK=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "%RK%" /V Personal'
) Do Echo CD /D "%%~B\Test\T1"
Copy /Y "text1.txt" "F:\Test\T1"
Pause
```

Or without the need for changing directory:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "RK=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "%RK%" /V Personal'
) Do Copy /Y "%%~B\Test\T1\text1.txt" "F:\Test\T1"
Pause
```

Comment: Very nice Compo, thanks. It works great but it still looks in C:\~Documents first, cannot find file, then goes to E:\~Documents and procceds with tasks. Is there a work-a-round for this?

@Echo
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /V Personal') Do cd /D %%B\Test
cd "T1"
COPY "text1.txt" "F:\Test\T1"

Comment: I've updated my answer to cater for your actual intent as well as the directory change, _which isn't required_.

Answer (score 0):

The data returned from `reg query` is not clean data for the query.

I get a CRLF, then the full key path, CRLF, and then the value, type
and data. Followed by at least another CRLF.

I will search for the value `Personal` in the 1st token of `%%A`.
The 2nd token of `%%B` has the data type which is not used here.
The 3rd token has the data wanted so it will be in `%%C` when
using `tokens=1,2*`.

```
@echo off
set "Personal="

for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%A in (
    'reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /V Personal'
) do if /i "%%~A" == "Personal" set "Personal=%%~C"

if not defined Personal exit /b 1

cd /d "%Personal%"
echo %cd%
pause
```

**Handling Tokens**

Example string:

> Personal    REG_SZ    D:\User\Documents With Spaces

Delims setting default is *spaces* and *tabs*. Use `for /?` for help.
Delims characters separate the tokens.

Start with `tokens=1` which will get 1st token `Personal`.

Add `,2` to be `tokens=1,2`, which will get 1st token `Personal` and
2nd token `REG_SZ`.

Add `*` to be `tokens=1,2*`  which will get 1st token `Personal`,
2nd token `REG_SZ` and 3rd token will glob the rest to be
`D:\User\Documents With Spaces`.

A comma between token pattern `2` and `*` is optional thus I did
not add a comma.

Using `%%A` as initial `for` variable, `%%A` contains 1st token,
`%%B` contains 2nd token. `%%C` contains 3rd token.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sirs,
I'm using Michael's method atm. There are many files that are being backed up. I do so enjoy learning new things. I don't quite understand the tokens yet but getting there.

```
set "Personal="
for /f "tokens=1,3" %%A in ('reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /V Personal') do if /i "%%~A" == "Personal" set "Personal=%%~B"
if not defined Personal exit /b 1
cd /d "%Personal%\A2A\FSX"

cd "B17"
>NUL COPY "B17log.dat" "F:\Dropbox\My FlightSim Backup\[user folder]\Documents\A2A\FSX\B17\B17log_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,5%.dat"

cd "..\377"
>NUL COPY "377log.dat" "F:\Dropbox\My FlightSim Backup\[user folder]\Documents\A2A\FSX\377\377log_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,5%.dat"
>NUL COPY "B377log.dat" "F:\Dropbox\My FlightSim Backup\[user folder]\Documents\A2A\FSX\377\B377log_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,5%.dat"
>NUL COPY "B377.dat" "F:\Dropbox\My FlightSim Backup\[user folder]\Documents\A2A\FSX\377\B377_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,5%.dat"
>NUL COPY "axisConfig.cfg" "F:\Dropbox\My FlightSim Backup\[user folder]\Documents\A2A\FSX\377\axisConfig.cfg"
```

Thanks again, much obliged
Roger

Comment: Fixed a bug in my answer with the reg data having a path with spaces. You may want to update your code.